# How to find context label using Python webdriver?

Tags: python, webdriver

With this HTML code, I would like to extract the text ".Fermé(e)" :

```
<A onclick="return false;" onkeydown=campaignSPTree.onKeyDown(this); href="#r2">
  <SPAN>
    <LABEL class=hidden-label>Tree level 0, 3 of 3. </LABEL>
    <SPAN id=r2c0Content name="r2c0Content">
        <IMG border=0 alt="" src="/wfo/bbm/images/icons/campaign.gif?v=11.1.1.7673"> UAT Sud Est
    </SPAN>
    <LABEL id=campaignSPTreer2ChildInfo class=hidden-label childInfo=", node has 24 items. Press the right arrow key to show/hide this row's child items.">.Fermé(e)</LABEL>
  </SPAN>
  <LABEL class=hidden-label name="SelectInfo"></LABEL>
</A>
```

I thought I could do it using the following command, but it doesn't work :

```
infoOpen = browser.find_element_by_id("campaignSPTreer2ChildInfo").text
```

I don't have an error message but the value infoOpen is empty.
Could you please help me ?

Comment: Did you try other identification methods besides by_id?

Comment: @0buz. Yes I try `infoOpen = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@id='campaignSPTreer0ChildInfo']").text`. It's the same result. Is it because of the beginning of text which begins with a point ?

Comment: Try identifying the `a` tag first perhaps? Then work your way to label with `a.find_element_by...`

Comment: @0buz. I don't understand

Comment: element1=broswer.<find tag A here (or another one above A>. Then
infoOpen=element1.<find label here>

Comment: 0buz I tried this : `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='r2c0Content']").text` and it works correctly.

Comment: 0buz. The text ".Fermé(e)" that I am trying to capture appears in an info window. Maybe that's why I can't see it ?